# How MPI_Alltoall() works?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I'm doing MPI programming and using its functions is a little bit unclear for me. Assume I have 4 processors, and each knows an array:

```
P0 : iarr{a0, a1, a2, a3}
P1 : iarr{b0, b1, b2, b3}
P2 : iarr{c0, c1, c2, c3}
P3 : iarr{d0, d1, d2, d3}
```

And I want another array (oarr) gets these values:

```
P0 : oarr{a0, b0, c0, d0}
P1 : oarr{a1, b1, c1, d1}
P2 : oarr{a2, b2, c2, d2}
P3 : oarr{a3, b3, c3, d3}
```

I know it's a classic example or MPI_Alltoall(), but my code isn't working. It generates some memory mapping info as the error result.

I'm coding in C and my code looks like this:

```
int *iarr = NULL, *oarr = NULL;
....
MPI_Alltoall(&iarr, P, MPI_INT, &oarr, P, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

iarr has some values and oarr ahs only 0s.
Am I doing it right?!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Some parts of error output:

```
[NYPC:20583] *** Process received signal ***
[NYPC:20583] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[NYPC:20583] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[NYPC:20583] Failing at address: 0x2
[NYPC:20582] *** Process received signal ***
[NYPC:20582] Signal: Aborted (6)
[NYPC:20582] Signal code:  (-6)
[NYPC:20583] [ 0] [0xb77d940c]
[NYPC:20583] [ 1] ./ex31(votes_mpi+0x18e) [0x8048e38]
[NYPC:20583] [ 2] ./ex31(main+0x1c0) [0x8048b6c]
[NYPC:20583] [ 3] /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0xb75684d3]
[NYPC:20582] [ 0] [0xb771740c]
[NYPC:20582] [ 1] [0xb7717424]
[NYPC:20582] [ 2] /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x4f) [0xb74bb1df]
[NYPC:20582] [ 3] /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x175) [0xb74be825]
[NYPC:20582] [ 4] /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6b39a) [0xb74f839a]
[NYPC:20582] [ 5] /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2) [0xb7502ee2]
```

Comment: Do not pass `&iarr` and `&oarr` to `MPI_Alltoall` but rather `iarr` and `oarr` (I hope you allocate memory for both arrays in advance and do not expect MPI to do it for you).

Comment: And in addition, as with your Gather question, keep in mind that it's the number of items *per* *processor* you want to pass to alltoall as a count.

Comment: Can you post a piece of code or a full text case, which can be used for understanding what you are doing?